# PLS - 00382 Expression is of wrong type

Tags: oracle11g

```
create or replace type demo_type as table (information2 varchar2(4000))

create or replace function demo_func(refnum in risk_headers.reference_num%type)
return varchar2
as 
info_type demo_type;

begin 
  select oth.information2 into info_type  from cnfgtr_otherdtls_grid_tab oth 
 where oth.grpid = 'GRP358' and oth.num_reference_number = refnum 
 and oth.information1 in (select rd.risk1 from risk_details rd where rd.reference_num = refnum);

return info_type;
end;
```

Getting error while returning from the function.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: while viewing the function in command prompt getting the error at return info_type;

Comment: You can't select into an array type like that. You should look up BULK_COLLECT. What is it you expect to do with this function? Incidentally, if you're expecting to return the array rather than just a string, you need to adjust your `RETURN VARCHAR2` to `RETURN DEMO_TYPE`.

Comment: @Boneist in select query i am expecting multiple rows with single column.But function returns only single data though i need to populate views using function.

Comment: why not just put the select directly into the views?

Comment: if i am including this select statement in the view then getting : ora 01427 single row subquery returns more than one row